# How to toggle multiple objects shade smooth / flat?

Tags: properties

Now i can only select and change one by one, and it's not possible to do that for hundreds of objects.

[image]

[image]

I select hierarchy of my buildings grp, and right click in 3d view does not return options about shade smooth or flat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select as much as you want, then right click -> Shade smooth -> all selected will get it.

[image]

Comment: I selected the whole hierarchy of a grp, and why there is no option about shade smooth/flat?

Comment: Just right click on any object (which you have selected ) in the 3D View

Comment: @Jolene  In Chris' example, all spheres are mesh objects. Your selection is mixed (Empty + mesh objects) and your *active* object is an Empty. There are *selected objects* and one *active object*. The *active object* is usually the one you selected last and it's highlighted in light orange/yellow, the *selected objects* are reddish. The context menu is for Empty objects because that's your active object. Make one of the mesh objects the active object (those with the numbers in the name) and it should work like in Chris' example.

Comment: Got it, the last object in selection matters what options would be given. Appreciate it!